# How to alert if there is a Dropzone error?

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

**This is my controller, where I return error**

```
if(!empty($chckDocsDup)){
     $return['error'] = 1;
     return response()->json($return);
     exit();
 }
```

In my Dropzone I getting those error using `this.on('error', function())` but it failed to alert. Any alternative idea?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var uplodURLother = '{{url(ADMIN."/uploaddocument")}}';
    var metaTokenOther = $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');
    var uploaddoctypeOther = $('#uploaddoctype_other').val();
    Dropzone.options.myDropOther = {
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx",
    url: uplodURLother,
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("_token", metaTokenOther);
        formData.append("doctype", uploaddoctypeOther);
        formData.append("candidateid", '{{$candidateDet['candidateid'] }}');
    },
      init: function() {
         this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
            $(".remv_"+file.doctype+"_"+file.filecnt).remove();
        });
        this.on('success', function(file, response) {
                alert('hai');
          });   
            this.on('error', function(file, response) {
               alert('response'); //This alert is not working
            });
      }
    };

});
```

Comment: You need to return an error http status code: `return new JsonResponse(['reason' => 'Some Reason'], 400);`

Comment: Can you please post the solution as answer

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, how are you going about your validation? Are you able to show the whole controller method?

Answer (score 1):

Dropzone checks to see if the upload failed by looking at the status code of the response.

When you do

```
return response()->json([]);
```

Laravel will by default return a 200 status code.

In order to return an error status, you need to do something like

```
return new JsonResponse([], 400);
```

You can change `400` to any of the `4xx` status codes (IE 422)

Comment: Thanks alot sir, I waste Lot of time for this simple solution